# Query for both daily aggregate, and then monthly aggregates in the same query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to count the number of daily unique active users by subreddit and day, and then aggregate these counts onto monthly unique active users by group and month.  Doing each one individually is simple enough, but when I try to do them in one combined query, it tells me that I need to group by date_month_day in my second-level subquery, which would result in monthly_unique_users being the same as daily_unique_uauthors..(Error: Expression 'date_month_day' is not present in the GROUP BY list [invalidQuery]).

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM
          (
              SELECT *,
                 (daily_unique_authors/monthly_unique_authors) * 1.0 AS ratio,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_month_day ORDER BY ratio DESC) rank 
                 FROM 
                     (
                      SELECT subreddit,
                            date_month_day,
                            daily_unique_authors,
                            SUM(daily_unique_authors) AS monthly_unique_authors,
                            LEFT(date_month_day, 7) as date_month
                            FROM 
                                  (
                                    SELECT subreddit,
                                           LEFT(DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)), 10) as date_month_day,
                                           COUNT(UNIQUE(author)) as daily_unique_authors
                                    FROM TABLE_QUERY([fh-bigquery:reddit_comments], "table_id CONTAINS \'20\' AND LENGTH(table_id)<8")
                                    GROUP EACH BY subreddit, date_month_day
                                  )
                            GROUP EACH BY subreddit, date_month))

     WHERE rank <= 100
     ORDER BY date_month ASC
```

The final output should ideally be something like:

```
subreddit date_month date_month_day daily_unique_users         monthly_unique_users ratio  

 1 google 2005-12    2005-12-29                       77                    600     0.128     
 2 google 2005-12    2005-12-31                       52                     600     0.866    
 3 google 2005-12    2005-12-28                       81                     600     0.135    
 4 google 2005-12    2005-12-27                       73                     600     0.121
```

Comment: can you please check the query you provided?! it is total mess and I don't see how it can produced the error you claim it produces! also, are you still bound for some reason to legacy sql?

Comment: Okay, I think that should be better. No I am not bound to legacy SQL. If there's anything else please let me know.

Comment: Legacy or standard, doesn't matter to me. Whichever is the 'preferred' method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date_month_day ORDER BY ratio DESC) rank 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      daily.subreddit subreddit, 
      daily.date_month date_month, 
      date_month_day, 
      daily_unique_authors, 
      monthly_unique_authors,
      1.0 * daily_unique_authors / monthly_unique_authors AS ratio
    FROM (
      SELECT subreddit,
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)) AS date_month_day,
        FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc))) AS date_month,
        COUNT(DISTINCT author) AS daily_unique_authors
      FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018*`
      GROUP BY subreddit, date_month_day, date_month
    ) daily
    JOIN (
      SELECT subreddit,
        FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc))) AS date_month,
        COUNT(DISTINCT author) AS monthly_unique_authors
      FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018*`
      GROUP BY subreddit, date_month
    ) monthly 
    ON daily.subreddit = monthly.subreddit
    AND daily.date_month = monthly.date_month
  )
)
WHERE rank <= 100
ORDER BY date_month
```

Note: I tried to leave the original logic and structure as much as possible as it is in the question  - so OP will be able to correlate answer with question and make further adjustments if needed :o)

Comment: Would there be a way to have it look at all possible reddit_comments.* tables, and not just 2018 using Standard SQL?

Comment: of course. just adjust wildcard and use _TABLE_SUFFIX - see more in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference

Comment: or  - just to keep it simple use `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.20*` instead of `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018*`  :o)  exactly as in your original logic. I narrowed down to 2018 only in my answer just to lower cost of query ...

Comment: FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 2007 and 2017 results in 'Error: Views cannot be queried through prefix. Using fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.20* results in Error: No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: STRING, INT64, INT64. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY) at [20:21] [invalidQuery]. EDIT: I lied, your second suggestion works!

Comment: see my latest comment - it should be `bigquery.reddit_comments.20*` - not just `bigquery.reddit_comments.*`   !

Comment: You're amazing, thank you so much for your help! Do you have any suggestions and resources on how one could get better at writing sql queries?

Comment: practice, practice & practice + read other posts. play with stuff. and obviously vote up the posts that you will like / or will help you. and obviously read documentation - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs :o)